# Broadcom STA Wireless drivers not working on Dell Inspiron 5420

Tags: dell, inspiron

I'm new to linux. I just started working on ubuntu 12.04. Wifi is not working on ubuntu. It works on Windows 7 though.

When I tried connecting to the net throght LAN it works. Also, through LAN I checked for additional drivers. There were no drivers found.

The command lspci -nn | grep 0280 gives me :
`02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`

Comment: Your pci-id of 14e4:4365 according to the http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 link is NOT supported by the b43 driver.  Unfortunately, it does not list any alternate either.  Try the broadcom drivers, then only if necessary, the ndiswrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link [Broadcom STA Wireless Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) for the initial help.  It has instructions on how to determine your card model and how to install if you have an internet connection or not.

If that doesn't get you anywhere, try this. I found this on a forum somewhere (credit to whoever wrote this):

Please try the b43 driver and firmware instead of the wl driver.

Please copy-paste the following commands into the Terminal (using a working, ***wired*** Internet connection):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Then please run the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Using the gedit editor, please REMOVE the following configuration lines in
the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
```

**Save** the change to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file after removing the 
configuration lines.

Then reboot and retest wireless.

**Source:** https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/178531

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Telorand was very useful, but then this error was in syslog:

```
Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
```

So I found [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/193713) page which recommended to use the `firmware-b43-installer` instead of `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`.

With a Dell Latitude D630 and the same problem this helped:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```